# How to put spacing between floating divs?

Tags: css, html

i have a parent div, which can change its size, depending on the available space. Within that div, i have floating divs. Now, i would like to have spacing between these divs, but no space to the parent div (see drawing).

[image]

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Thank you

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found a solution, which at least helps in my situation, it probably is not suitable for other situations:

I give all my green child divs a complete margin:

```
margin: 10px;
```

And for the surrounding yellow parent div i set a negative margin:

```
margin: -10px;
```

I also had to remove any explicit width or height setting for the yellow parent div, otherwise it did not work.

This way, in absolute terms, the child divs are correctly aligned, although the parent yellow div obviously is set off, which in my case is OK, because it will not be visible.

Comment: There's only one downside to this approach: if your parent div sits flush with the right hand side of the page (or within 10px of it), the 10px of negative margin will overlap the edge of the window, widening the page and causing a horizontal scrollbar.

This can be more of an issue with responsive design where you need to start dealing with viewport widths that are sometimes as narrow as 320px in total.

Comment: Note: that said, I certainly haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. As I said, it is certainly not applicable in all situations.

Comment: @thomasrutter Would just applying the margins to the top and left sides help?

Comment: In some cases you might need to add a wrapper with the negative margins, a small cost for a broad and clean solution among what CSS gives. Works nicely with flex too. +1

Answer (score 14):

You can do the following:

Assuming your container div has a class "yellow".

```
.yellow div {
    // Apply margin to every child in this container
    margin: 10px;
}

.yellow div:first-child, .yellow div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    // Remove the margin on the left side on the very first and then every fourth element (for example)
    margin-left: 0;
}

.yellow div:last-child {
    // Remove the right side margin on the last element
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The number 3n+1 equals every fourth element outputted and will clearly only work if you know how many will be displayed in a row, but it should illustrate the example. [More details regarding nth-child here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

**Note:** For :first-child to work in IE8 and earlier, a `<!DOCTYPE>` must be declared.

**Note2:** The :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but as i said in my question, the container can change its size, so there might be room for more than three divs in a row.

Answer (score 6):

Add `margin` to your div style

```
margin:0 10px 10px 0;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: but that puts a margin at the very bottom as well, means space between the bottom green divs and the bottom border of the yellow div. Don't want that.

Comment: Sorry. I was going by your text and didn't double check your diagram. I don't think there is a pure CSS solution to this - certainly not a good cross browser one. I would use JavaSCript to figure out which divs are on the second line, assign a class to them and give that class `margin-bottom:0`. I dont think you can get much better.

Comment: this will add the margin bottom to all div and create space with main div that's not required in question here.

Comment: @punit Thanks for reestablishing that. Actually the OP never mentioned margin on the bottom.

Comment: hi, ok, so it seems then, it is not possible. too bad, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party but... I've had a similar situation come up and I discovered [padding-right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-right) (and bottom, top, left too, of course). From the way I understand its definition, it puts a padding area *inside* the inner `div` so there's no need to add a negative margin on the parent as you did with a margin.

```
padding-right: 10px;
```

This did the trick for me!

Comment: Since this padding is inside the div, it will have the background color of the div. In this case, it would be 10px of green at the right edge of green div. For example, if the green div contains text, it will ensure there is no text in that 10px - but it won't make that area yellow. Therefore not useful in OP's situation. But good for people to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just a case of applying an appropriate class to each div?

For example:

```
.firstRowDiv { margin:0px 10px 10px 0px; }
.secondRowDiv { margin:0px 10px 0px 0px; }
```

This depends on if you know in advance which div to apply which class to.

Comment: hi, yes, well, as i tried to say, the divs are floating and the parent div can change its size, so i cannot know, where each div will be.

Answer (score -2):

A litte late answer.

If you want to use a grid like this, you should have a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), It's relatively easy to install, and it gives you exactly what you are looking for, all wrapped in nice and simple html/css + it works easily for making websites responsive.

Comment: Give an example! Just "use Bootstrap" does not help me at all. Actually I *am* using Bootstrap and have this question.